# Java - ItemListener not listening to my components?

Tags: java, swing, itemlistener

I took a segment of my program and put the code here. *Basically the issue is that the item listener method isnt being called*. Here if the user selects the right answer and presses "submit" an actionlistener method will tell him/her if they got the answer right.

```
static boolean answer = false; // returns this as true if user got question right

public void QuizPanel() {
    QuizPanel = new JPanel();
    QuizPanel.setLayout(null); // default layout

    JLabel label = new JLabel( "True/False- Java is Object Orientated?");
    label.setBounds(10, 50, 400, 20);
    QuizPanel.add(label);

    option1 = new JCheckBox("True"); 
    option1.setSelected(false);
    option1.setBounds(10, 70, 120, 40);                         
    QuizPanel.add(option1);
    option1.addItemListener(this); // Adds a item listener

    option2 = new JCheckBox("False");
    option2.setSelected(false);
    option2.setBounds(40, 70, 120, 40);
    QuizPanel.add(option2);
    option2.addItemListener(this);

    ///////////////////////////////////////

    JButton submit = new JButton("SUBMIT ANSWER:");
    submit.setBounds(10, 100, 150, 20);
    QuizPanel.add(submit);

    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // Action Listener      
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt2) {
            System.out.println ("Your answer is " + answer); // Got it right?
        }
    });
}

public void itemStateChanged1(ItemEvent e1) { 
    Object source = e.getItemSelectable();          
    if (source == option1) { 
        answer = true;
    } else {
        //nothing- stays false
    }       
}
```

Nothing happens and it doesn't tell the user if he/she got it right/wrong.

Comment: `e.getItemSelectable();` logic dictates that this code shouldn't even compile. Also, for better help sooner, please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: Are you using an IDE to write this?

Comment: This code does not compile whatsoever, starting with the ; you forgot on the line with the System.out.println(), and ending with not implementing ItemListener methods (yours is itemStateChanged1. Why the 1?)

Comment: Because I have three methods (3 quiz panels). You wont believe this but the first one works with the same code I posted. I am starting to think you can only have '1' itemchange method. I dont know how to configure a ItemStatechange method to a specific method though..

Comment: `this is just SSCCE.` - it is NOT a SSCCE. How is the code you posted compilable or executable?

Comment: Please ***read*** about the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) & stop applying the term to (uncompilable) code snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QuizPanel = new JPanel();
```

Use standard Java naming conventions. Variable names should not start with an upper case character:

```
QuizPanel.setLayout(null);
...
label.setBounds(10, 50, 400, 20);
```

Don't use a null layout and setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with a Layout Manager.

```
public void itemStateChanged1(ItemEvent e1) throws IOException
```

I don't know how your code compiles. You are implementing the wrong method. Also, why would an ItemListener throw an IOException?

Too many little mistakes to guess what you are doing wrong. Post a proper SSCCE.

Comment: I fixed some of the little mistakes.I didnt copy paste... SSCCE is off  ok

Comment: Nothing looks changes to me. No SSCCE, none of the suggestions fixed, so I guess you really don't want any help.

Comment: I can change the variables into proper convention but updating the layout would be irrelevant to the problem. I still can never understand why is the System.out.println not showing?

Comment: Your ItemListener doesn't even have a println() statement. Until you can post a proper SSCCE, I doubt you will get help. You are just wasting our time because the code you have posted makes no sense.

Comment: I removed the IO Exception, rewrote some lines of code and used proper notation. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You say `Object source = e.getItemSelectable();` 
but you declare `e1` as your `ItemEvent`.
 Try changing `Object source = e.getItemSelectable();` to `Object source = e1.getItemSelectable();`.

Comment: @BDillan fix it then? Your providing people here on SO with invalid information

Comment: I edited it. I just don't know where else to look for help, and I don't know why its not calling the itemlistener method. I hoped someone can give me a solution because I dont know what to add to the code.